# Update total enemy counter after single enemy is defeated?

Tags: c#, unity

So I have a list that counts how many enemies are in the area. But when I kill an enemy, the list shows that that element in that array is missing, and doesn't reduce the enemy counter. How can I get it to reflect when an enemy is defeated?

**Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EnemyCount : MonoBehaviour {
public List<Transform> enemies;

void Start () {
    enemies = new List<Transform>();
}

void Update () {
    FindAllEnemies();
}

public void FindAllEnemies () {
    GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

    foreach (GameObject enemy in go) {
        //Checks for duplicates
        if (!enemies.Contains(enemy.transform)) {
            AddEnemiesToList(enemy.transform);
        }
    }
}

public void AddEnemiesToList (Transform enemy) {
    enemies.Add(enemy);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, one way to achieve it would be to clear the list each frame to make sure you list is always up to date. Please note that I do not know exactly the syntax to clear a list, but your function would look like this:

```
public void FindAllEnemies () {
    GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

    enemies.Clear(); // Probably not the right function name... 
    foreach (GameObject enemy in go) {
        enemies.Add(enemy.transform);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In fact, you could even do something like this if it suits your needs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EnemyCount : MonoBehaviour {

  public List<GameObject> enemies;

  void Start () {
    enemies = new List<GameObject>();
  }

  void Update () {
    FindAllEnemies();
  }

  public void FindAllEnemies () {
    enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. So simple, can't believe I didn't think of that.. Thank you!